# What is the App_Data folder used for in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, security, app-data

When creating a new ASP.NET application in Visual Studio, a couple of files and folders are created automatically. One of those folders is called `App_Data`.

Also when publishing a website by selecting the menu option `Build->Publish` a checkbox is available `Include files from the App_Data folder`.

Am I right assuming that the files put in this file and its sub-folders are not going to be accessible through the web? For example, would it be safe to put in that folder resources that I only intend to be used by the application code?

What is the real intended use of the `App_Data` folder?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all the answers. From the answers received so far I am interested mostly in two points mentioned:

1. [App_Data is essentially a storage point for file-based data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-appdata-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio/528876#528876)
2. [It should not be viewable by the web and is a place for the web app to store and read data from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-appdata-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio/528872#528872)

Would someone be able specify how the "not viewable by the web" is ensured? 
Can I rely on that fact when performing standard deployment, or do I need to check some IIS settings on the server as well.

In the situation when I have a set of pdf files that I want to be accessible only from the application. Would App_Data folder be the right place to use, or should I create a separate folder and manually set IIS to ensure that it is not accessible by Web?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

App_Data is essentially a storage point for file-based data stores (as opposed to a SQL server database store for example). Some simple sites make use of it for content stored as XML for example, typically where hosting charges for a DB are expensive.

Comment: Thanks annakata for this answer. I think the important point to add is that the content of App_Data is by default not viewable by the web as mentioned by JaredPar. and also as you commented "this behaviour can be modified from *.config httphandlers"

Comment: Does app_data folder contain the references to local web services? My web application works fine in .net F5 run. But web services don't work after packaging and deploying in ISS... :(

Comment: Also this folder is used for storing a local database files.

Comment: One thing that hasen't been mentioned is that IIS reboots the web process when a file is changed, but App_Data is excluded from this!

Answer (score 48):

in IIS, highlight the machine, double-click "Request Filtering", open the "Hidden Segments" tab.  "App_Data" is listed there as a restricted folder.  Yes i know this thread is really old, but this is still applicable.

Answer (score 26):

The intended use of App_data is to store application data for the web process to acess.  It should not be viewable by the web and is a place for the web app to store and read data from.

Comment: Not just "should not", anything in that folder is blocked from being served by ASP.NET

Comment: @John, I was under the impression there were ways to "change" that behavior.  Yes, definately evil to do so but I don't know how common or not that is

Comment: How is that "not viewable" achived? Would the App_data folder have a specific settings in IIS?

Comment: @padn, I'm not 100% sure about the stack but it is either special cased in IIS or the Asp.Net stack.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Comment: iirc this behaviour can be modified from *.config httphandlers

Answer (score 16):

It's a place to put an embedded database, such as Sql Server Express, Access, or SQLite.

Comment: Or any other data the site might use like, for example, XML files (like a list of states/countries/etc)

Comment: Is is a the database only then? Can I put say some e.g. pdf files in it which I want to access thought the code only, e.g using Response.TransmitFile method?

Comment: anything - the concept of data doesn't specify a filetype or format

Answer (score 13):

The App_Data folder is a folder, which your asp.net worker process has files sytem rights too, but isn't published through the web server.

For example we use it to update a local CSV of a *contact us* form. If the preferred method of emails fails or any querying of the data source is required, the App_Data files are there.

It's not ideal, but it it's a good fall-back.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation about *[ASP.NET Web Project Folder Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* in MSDN:

> You can keep your Web project's files in any folder structure that is
>   convenient for your application. To make it easier to work with your
>   application, ASP.NET reserves certain file and folder names that you
>   can use for specific types of content.
>
> **App_Data** contains application data files including .mdf database files, XML files, and other data store files. The App_Data folder is
>   used by ASP.NET to store an application's local database, such as the
>   database for maintaining membership and role information. For more information, see [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Understanding Role Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 8):

The main intention is for keeping your application's database file(s) in.

And no this will not be accessable from the web by default.

Answer (score 7):

We use it as a temporary storage area for uploaded csv files. Once uploaded, an ajax method processes and deletes the file.

Answer (score 6):

The intended use for App_Data is to store database related file. Usually SQL Server Express .mdf files.