# Medium-Trust File I/O permission

Tags: asp.net, file-io, medium-trust

According to this [MSDN article about medium trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx#paght000020_mediumtrustsummary), under medium-trust:

> FileIOPermission is restricted. This
>   means you can only access files in
>   your application's virtual directory
>   hierarchy. Your application is granted
>   Read, Write, Append, and PathDiscovery
>   permissions for your application's
>   virtual directory hierarchy.

However, for my current hosting provider runs applications under medium-trust and when I try to read/write a file in the application's root folder, I get a `access to path 'myfile.xml' denied` error.

This file is read using the following bit of code

```
XElement file = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/myfile.xml"));
```

**Update Full Error:**

> Access to the path
>   'C:\WebSites\mywebsite\myfile.xml' is
>   denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   'C:\WebSites\mywebsite\myfile.xml' is
>   denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7,
>   and the configured application pool
>   identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating.
>   If the application is impersonating
>   via ,
>   the identity will be the anonymous
>   user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or
>   the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   to the path
>   'C:\WebSites\mywebsite\myfile.xml' is
>   denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +12892935    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
>   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean
>   useLongPath) +2481
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   +229    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share) +102
>   System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String
>   outputFileName) +5224496
>   System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Save(String
>   fileName, SaveOptions options) +108
>   mesoBoard.Services.SiteConfig.UpdateCache()
>   +1971    mesoBoard.Web.MvcApplication.OnApplicationStarted()
>   +62    Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication.Application_Start()
>   +604
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Access to
>   the path
>   'C:\WebSites\mywebsite\myfile.xml' is
>   denied.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +3985477
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +325 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +407 
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +375
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Access to
>   the path
>   'C:\WebSites\mywebsite\myfile.xml' is
>   denied.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +11524352
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +141
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4782309

Comment: Please show the full stack trace and message of the exception. It's not clear if this is a CAS (CLR) security exception or an NTFS file permission issue.

Comment: @Elion - updated with full error.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? Are there any other processes that may hold a lock on the myfile.xml file?

Comment: IIS 7.5, I'm on a shared host, no other process should be using it except my web application, which could be accessed by multiple users, but not edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the user account of the Application Pool running the website has read/write permissions to the file/folder. By default, I think you should have read permissions but not write permissions.  Also, for security reasons, it might be a good idea to move that file out of the wwwroot folder into something that can't corrupt your entire application.

> webdir/data
>   webdir/data/**myfile.xml**
>
> webdir/wwwroot
>   webdir/wwwroot/default.aspx

Comment: Is there anyway to read/write files without having to make sure the permissions are there? I mean, if my application is meant to create new files that need read/write access and my users are not tech savy, is there a way around that?

Comment: I found some info on setting file permissions here (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Miscellaneous/Q_23444174.html) or just Google `asp.net set file permissions`

Answer (score 0):

Your IO permission sounds like it's just a permission issue with your file. I know what whenever I upload a file to my hosting provider, I have to login to their control panel and manually give the IIS account write access to it, as read access is the only permission granted automatically.

On another note, the location of your xml file poses a security issue. Try putting the file in the "~/App_Data/" folder, it's a special .NET folder that's more restricted than your data folder - at the moment I could go to www.yoursite.com/data/myfile.xml and download it, whereas any file in the App_Data folder can't be downloaded over the web.

[What is the App_Data folder used for in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the XElement class. The namespace "System.Xml.Linq" is probably not allowed in your hosting "medium level" configuration. To use Linq in medium level trust, please follow the following [procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907622.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Medium Trust specifies that the application only has access to the $AppDir.  You can customize medium Trust level to add additional access to the medium trust by altering the FileIOPermission to include other directories than $AppDir.  However, I found that when you call Server.MapPath("/") under even a customized Medium Trust Level, then you will get an exception "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed"

It is my theory that this is because you are requesting access to the file system outside the of the $AppDir".  We ended up having to remove all calls to Server.MapPath() from our web applications.

Answer (score -1):

I set up a website on GoDaddy and found that the only way I could enable write access, was to enable it for the *whole web root* but that might have just been the restriction for that hosting plan?