# System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission Error When Trying to Upload a File Based on Trust Levels

Tags: c#, asp.net, medium-trust, full-trust

I am developing a web application on Visual Studio 2013. In my application, users are able to upload images(*saving to computer's file system for local, saving to server's file system after publishing*). I published web site to my hosting. But there was a problem on uploading. I contacted with the support and they told me that they don't allow **Full Tust**, they allow **Medium** Trust level for application. I added following line to set application's trust level to medium in my web.config:

```
<trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
```

But when I upload file to try, I encountered with following error:

> **Description**: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Is there a way to give myself **fileiopermission** on medium trust level? I am searching for the solution for weeks but nothing come in handy.

Here is the code that causing problem.

```
foreach (var file in uploadImages.PostedFiles)
{
    //this line causes the problem
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(new FileInfo(file.FileName).Name);
    string[] extension = filename.Split('.'); 
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/fortunePictures/" + randomString(16) + "." + extension.Last().ToString());
    file.SaveAs(path); 
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string date = (now.ToString("u"));
    date = date.Substring(0,date.Length-1);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    insertImage(file, path, date, img, userID, fortuneID);
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath) +157
   System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost) +42
   System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName) +46
   Fal_Sitesi.kahve.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ömer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Fal Sitesi\Fal Sitesi\kahve.aspx.cs:84
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9717914
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6720
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +22
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.kahve_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in App_Web_n3utt0vk.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Please help.

**Edit: What I've done so far**

I added Security policy configuration according to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx) I got

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpException: Unable to read the
>   security policy file for trust level 'Medium'.

error. I tried to create custom security policy file and change **FileIOPermission** contents other than $AppDir$. But it didn't help either. Then I create new web.config file. I copied contents of web_mediumtrust.config. But didn't solve either. At the end I removed **security policy** tag and all its content. And I used

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="mywebsite.com\ftpUserID" password="ftpPassword"/>
```

to connect server with authorization. But I was unable to make connection. (*I don't know why, with same data I can establish ftp connection.*)

As a result nothing solved my problem and I'm eager to solve it. Here is my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
      <httpRuntime/>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="index.aspx"/>
      <trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I get **System.Security.SecurityException** with this configuration.

**Edit 2:** I added   `<location path="myAppName" allowOverride="false">` to my configuration file according to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178693.aspx). Now the application works on **localhost** correctly. But the published web site still throws error. Here is the last version of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <location path="myAppName" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
      <httpRuntime/>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="index.aspx"/>
      <trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From above error message, it clearly shows that you need full trust permission to run your application. Please ask your hosting provider to give full permission for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but they only allow medium trust permission. I already solved the problem as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution and it was very simple :( In my case I used

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(new FileInfo(file.FileName).Name);
```

to get filename and it was unnecessary. I don't know why I did but

```
string filename = file.FileName
```

was enough to get filename of uploaded file. Rest of code is same and last status of web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration> 
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
      <httpRuntime/>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="index.aspx"/>
      <trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with medium trust.

You should be able to solve it using identity impersonation in configuration :

```
<system.web>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="HOSTING\myUserName" password="myPassword"/>
</system.web>
```

More details here :
https://forums.asp.net/t/1052417.aspx

The exact procedure to get working login depends of your hosting solution, about which you don't give any detail.

You can also find some resources on SO : [Unable to upload a file in medium trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306016/unable-to-upload-a-file-in-medium-trust) for example but this specific question refers to another which seems to have been deleted for whatever reason.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But i didn't help me so far. My hosting provider is [IHS](http://www.ihs.com.tr/). So solution may be different than GoDaddy.

I tried impersonation but didn't help either. I encountered with

    `Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The username or password is incorrect.`

Actually everyone can upload file in my application, so I don't think
the problem is authentication.
Also I can't read(and write) files from my computer. How can I give myself that permission?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if

`<trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>`
works. Can you confirm if it is correct?

Comment: Are you sure to have properly did it ? Here's another page on the subject : https://practicalhost.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203019788-Modified-Medium-Trust-and-adding-impersonation-on-PracticalHost-Cloud-Hosting You could also directly ask to your hosting provider to give you guidelines.

Comment: I used `<identity impersonate="true" userName="mywebsite.com\ftpUserID"  password="ftpPassword"/>` as your link advises but didn't help either. Also I asked my hosting provider but they said I should make changes in my software, changing web.config file won't help **alone**.

Comment: "Change the software" is a common answer from Ops guys ;). Do they suggest WHAT to change ? Server.MapPath seems all right for me even in medium trust environment and your code is simple... Have you read other links, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126337/medium-trust-file-i-o-permission ? Also, it would be interesting for us to check which line exactly of your code throws the exception. And I don't know if your "originUrl" does anything useful, I guess no but not sure.

Comment: I know :( They didn't suggest any spesific change. I read nearly every link for this problem yet I'm unable to find solution. 

Also `string filename = Path.GetFileName(new FileInfo(file.FileName).Name);` line throws exception. When I don't add `<trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>` line, I am able to read file from my computer and write to another directory in my computer. But when I add this line, I get error.

Comment: Could you please post your web.config and summarize in first post what you've already done ? I've also seen a link with somebody who suggest to remove compilation debug="false", don't ask me why :)