# Problem loading an image in web application (visual studio )

Tags: visual-studio-2008

HI.
I am doing a web project... I am still a beginner with visual studio.
I am using VS 2008. I have created a table grid view on which after i am creating a column, i inserted an image and then selected a destination url to the image which was added to App_Data folder.

I can see the image while editing but when i go for running the web, I cant see the image in the web browser, instead it shows image cannot be shown and can see a blank image space with the small image icon..

please help me.. how can i make it visible during running!? i have the visible property set to true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images do not belong in `app_data`. It is used as a storage location for file based data stores (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio) SO question and answers).

Create an `images` folder, put the image in it and reference the image from that location.