# Connect to database in App_Data folder

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Is it possible to connect to a database in the App_Data project folder using the command line? I'm trying to test some SQL statements outside of the VS environment.

I tried using the below, but that didn't seem to work:

```
sqlcmd -S .\Sqlexpress -d [location of mdf]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the app_data folder, but if you have the db files running off of a sql install, you can use sqlcmd command line which is installed with the sql client tools or the sql feature pack (sql native client).

Comment: yeah i tried to using sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d [location of mdf] but that didn't seem to work

Comment: And when you connect to your sql express install with management studio, do you see that database?  I've never heard of an .mdf running outside of a sql server except the compact edition.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio

Comment: So if it's not in .\SQLEXPRESS , you need to attach the file through management studio or commands in sqlcmd.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1007468.aspx/1?Howto+use+MSSQL+2005+Express+database+mdf+in+app_data+folder+ - From that, I would say that VS is acting as the DB server and you will not be able to interact unless you attach to a proper sql server.

Comment: I don't have management studio. Is it necessary? Also, if the connection string says that my datasource is ./SqlExpress then why can't I connect to it via command line. sorry for the confusion.