# asp.net database connection with Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access

I want to make a login page with an Access database for a school project with asp.net. I dont have really experience with C# so im doing different tutorials.

```
protected void Login1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=http://tmti-16.ict-lab.nl/database/ek2012.mdb";
    string query = "Select Count(*) From users Where username = ? And userpassword = ?";
    int result = 0;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", UserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Password.Text);
            conn.Open();
            Session["User"] = UserName.Text;
            result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Literal1.Text = "Invalid credentials";
    }
}
```

In Access I have the table 'users' with the 'username' and 'userpassword' rows.

Comment: What is your **problem**?? also you should add the **homework** tag to your question

Comment: Well I cant get a connection with it. I get the following error: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Your connection string should reference a local path for mdb files. If it's an asp.net project, you can put your access database mdb file into the App_Data folder and your connection string data source section becomes Data Source=|DataDirectory|ek2012.mdb;

Comment: Yes, its working! Thanks for helping. Now practicing more c# and looking in future for MVC 3 developing. I'm still consider to learn PHP or C# first :-)

Comment: Hi @Dash any chance of posting that as an answer?

Comment: @Remou - was planning to - just busy :-) See Below.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are encountering is almost certainly to do with the data source segment of your connection string:

```
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=http://tmti-16.ict-lab.nl/database/ek2012.mdb"
```

The Access mdb file should be on a local path. This can be anywhere on your local file system that the account your web application is running as has permission to access, but, usefully, ASP.Net actually has a better place to put these files, the [App_Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio).

If you place your mdb file in this folder, your connection string would then become:

```
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|ek2012.mdb"
```

The contents of the App_Data folder will not be served to clients so this is a secure place to put your data. It's also a good idea to use it as it keeps the data with the project; often, people will put data related files in a file system folder outside of the web root, which means you then have to remember this dependency when moving the site to another computer.

A common issue you might have with accessing files in App_Data is usually related to permissioning; the user you are running the code as will need read and write permissions in this directory in order to modify the mdb file. This is covered in the section ["Configuring Permissions for an Access Database" in this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445z2s49%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).