# ASP.NET Protect files inside folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a shared hosting account in which I upload my ASP.NET application. I let the user upload .doc files inside a folder, the problem is I only want logged users to be able to download those files, so I wrote a dispatcher, you give it the id and it reads the file and writes it to the browser, hiding the file location, nevertheless I want to protect the directory where all the files are, so you can only download files using the dispatcher, I tried marking it as a password protected directory, but now ASP.NET can't get access either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to restrict the NTFS permissions on that folder to only allow the user your applicaiton is running as.  This might be difficult in a shared host environment...

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be to move the folder outside of the site root but I guess as you are using shared hosting this may not be possible.

One other solution would be to move docs to the App_Data folder which is protected by .NET (see here [What is the App_Data folder used for in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio))