# Display image in a View, file is not found

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4

I want display image in my View. But file isn't found, file exist.

```
 string file = Server.MapPath("~") + @"/App_Data/Plakaty/" + wyd.WydarzenieId.ToString() + ".jpg";
 ViewBag.file_exist = System.IO.File.Exists(file);
```

I try: (Is display only alt:)

```
  @if (ViewBag.file_exist == true) // it's TRUE
        {
            <img src="../../App_Data/Plakaty/1029.jpg" alt="p" />
            <img src="~/App_Data/Plakaty/1029.jpg" alt="p1" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data/Plakaty/1029.jpg")"  alt="image"/>
            <img src="@Url.Content("../../App_Data/Plakaty/1029.jpg")"  alt="image2"/>

        }
```

Comment: So you are saying that `ViewBag.file_exist` is true?

Comment: @vonv. yes, it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="../../App_Data/Plakaty/1029.jpg" alt="p" />
```

Taking this as example, is App_Data really in the path for the image to the outside world? Sometimes internal paths are different.

Comment: I change App_Data folder to another to put my images and it's work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio