# Name a database through the connection string (App_Data deleted)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know where to *name* my database inside a connection string, like this one:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

For what I've reading, the name should be placed next to `|DataDirectory|`, but the fact is that I've **deleted** the `App_Data` folder, because I don't want to have a folder with such a name in my project, so the file `.mdf` won't be create, and I neither want to be.

What I want is that when going to the `Server Explorer` view inside *Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web* I could see the database with the name I've selected above, whichever it is.

**ADDITIONAL**:

- I would like to know what are the **pros/cons** of **not** having an `App_Data` folder.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions. You should stick to asking a single question at a time. See this information about App Data Folder. [What is the App_Data folder used for in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; here, mydatabase is your database name.

Comment: Do you want an MDF in your application (in which case you might as well use `App_Data`), or do you want a regular DB in your SQL Server instance (in which case you should just create it)?

Comment: @Kuzgun: I've tested it, and now I see what my problem was. The `Server Explorer` shows me the name of the `Connection String` not the database one. @SLaks: I want a regular SQL Server instance, for what I'm using `Code-First` for creating it. Which are the differences between those both?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no pros/cons.** Visual Studio creates temporary Database inside **App_Data** so that you can test it locally. I prefer hosting Database outside of project *(it is just my person preference)*.

Once the application is ready for production. We need to host the database in separate SQL Server. For example,

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
   connectionString="Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=TheUsername;Password=ThePassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" />
```

Here are [SQL Server connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: What if I want to rename the `App_Data` folder, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you'll manually have to set the permissions as App_Data is one of the only places configured for write access by the server process. Are you renaming it simply because you don't like the name? If so, that's not a good reason for breaking from standard conventions.

Comment: Have no much to say, just that I don't like that name conventions for folders. I think just deleting it, and working with the `Server Explorer` will be fine for now.

Comment: @Federico You do not want to rename **App_Data** as msm8bball stated. **App_Data** is standard name, and it services the other purpose too besides database. If you do not like database located inside **App_Data**, you can host it in **SQL Server**.

Comment: That is what I did, but I even don't want `App_Data` and `App_Start` in my project. The applications seems to keep working fine without them, so they can't be **that** important.

Comment: @Federico App_Data is not required, but still need App_Start for new ASP.Net Projects.

Comment: I've deleted and all things runs just fine, it is needed for what?