# File exists but, Status 404 File not Found

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, path, file-not-found

First of all, I'm using Chrome browser for development.

I have placed the files in the following order:

[image]

In Markup, I placed its reference like this:

```
<link href="App_Data/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is the original path: `root/App_Data/css/bootstrap.min.css.`

The file is available at the path, but still, the browser can't find the file with an error shown in the picture below:

[image]

I am confused. Why is it not able to find the file from the correct path? :S
What mistake am I making? (My previous question was also about the path. I tried following my last question's guide, but that also is not resolving this issue. Please look into it and tell me the possible issues. Thank you).

Comment: Can you check the file permissions? Does it have read access on it for other users?

Comment: if this is asp.net make sure that your server is running and you set permission to read from this folder

Comment: @HassanElsherbiny  these file have access to be read and yes, it is asp.net and i am running it on the server (IIS) debugging mode

Comment: @kiran.koduru these file have access to be read

Comment: have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Is the app_data in your localhost folder?

Comment: I've just found a solution, i'll post an answer.

Comment: Is this ASP.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[App_Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/528858/664342) is not typically used to publish web content, and is not published by default.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!  Feels like a pretty sparse answer, but it sounds like it got you pointed in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure App_Data is a special folder in MVC, consider moving the files in to a "content" folder or something (as is the standard).

Also try prefixes like "./" or "/" or "../" as depending on the url of the current page you may want to have a different path for these resources or always generate one that's relative from the root of the site.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a solution with the help of someone who commented here but deleted the comment. He was correct! I couldn't see his nickname. I'd prefer him to answer, i'll Tick his answer.

`APP_data` folder in asp.net doesn't let browser load `Css` and `JS` files as this folder is standard for Class files e.g. ( `abc.cs` ) .

I just moved all of these files in a new folder i created with the name `Content` and moved all css and js files in it, referenced it in `Html` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Heh that was me, but I started to second-guess myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try relative path as below, it might help you-

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start with the root of your application.App_Data is just a folder in Microsoft Visual Studio context.Once you publish your app it will not be the same.
For your question, this would be the solution:

```html
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will resolve the path from the app root.