# What is the meaning of root of website means

Tags: asp.net-webpages

I am studying the ASP.NET Webpages in my home.
While I was studying and I have some questions that I want to know.
I am learning "Creating a Text File and Writing Data to It".
The steps were 
1. Create a new folder named App_Data, if it doesn't exist already.

2. At the root of your website, create a new file named UserData.cshtml.
3. Replace the existing content with the following:

What does the "at the root of your website" means?

Comment: "at the root of your website" is the main folder which holds all the files and folders of your website

Comment: So, is it okay to create any file name outside the app_data folder? or inside the app_data folder?

Comment: according to the 2 first steps of your tuto, the userdata.cshtml file should be created in the root folder not in the App_data folder

Comment: Thanks for answering!.  Do you know what is  App_Data for?

Comment: I'm not an asp.net expert, but in this discussion: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio) , the App_Data is mainly created to hold all files related to data storage